# Open local html file with parameters in default broswer on windows

Tags: windows, winapi, browser

I need to open html file on disk with parameters from within my C++ program in default browser.

For example: c:\index.html?id=15 .

I am using ShellExecute, to open all urls or files, but this one does not work, it strips parameters from local files.

```
ShellExecute(0, NULL, "file:///c:\index.html?id=15", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

It works fine from command line i.e. 
iexplore file:///c:\index.html?id=15

How can I open that page?

Comment: The file:// url scheme doesn't have any allowance for HTTP parameters.

Comment: You could write `<html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='file:///c:\index.html?id=15'"> ...` to a temp file and shellexecute that instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this code.

```
int result = 0;
TCHAR app[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };

result = (int)::FindExecutable(_T("C:\\index.html"), NULL, app);
if (result > 32) {
  ::ShellExecute(0, NULL, app,
     _T("file:///C:\\index.html?id=15"), NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
}
```